# How to mock a static method inside a factory class

Tags: unit-testing, static, mockito, junit4, powermock

I need to mock the behavior of a static method inside a non-static factory class. The implementation of the class is:

**ABCFactory.java**

```
public class ABCFactory extends BaseUserFactory
{
    private static final ABCFactory factory = new ABCFactory();

    public static final ABCFactory getFactory()
    {
        return factory;
    }

    public Context getContext(String authority)
    {
        return (Context)createInstance(authority);
    }

    private ABCFactory()
    {
    }

    protected Class getInterface()
    {
        return ABCFactory.class;
    }
}
```

Now, this class is used in my code to get the profile something like:

---

**Document.java:**

```
Profile profile = ABCFactory.getFactory().getContext(authority).currentProfile();
```

I need to mock the ABCFactory class so that I can send my own context/profile object as a return type while testing. I've tried a bunch of methods but nothing seems to work here. Here's what I tried in my junit test class.

---

*Try 1:*
**DocumentTest.java**

```
ABCFactory mockABCFactory = Mockito.mock(ABCFactory.class);
ServiceProviderRegistrar.getRegistrar().bind(ABCFactory.class).toMockInstance(mockABCFactory);
Mockito.when(mockABCFactory .getFactory()).thenReturn(null);
Mockito.when(mockABCFactory .getContext(domain)).thenReturn(null);
```

***Error:***
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

---

*Try 2:* (Using PowerMock to avoid the new call.
**DocumentTest.java**

```
ABCFactory mockABCFactory = Mockito.mock(ABCFactory.class);
ServiceProviderRegistrar.getRegistrar().bind(ABCFactory.class).toMockInstance(mockABCFactory);
  try
  {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ABCFactory.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockABCFactory);
    PowerMockito.when(ABCFactory.getFactory()).thenReturn(mockABCFactory);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
Mockito.when(mockABCFactory.getContext(domain)).thenReturn(null);
```

***Error:***
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:490)

---

*Try 3:* (Used PowerMock.mockStatic)
**DocumentTest.java**

```
ABCFactory mockABCFactory= Mockito.mock(ABCFactory.class);
  ServiceProviderRegistrar.getRegistrar().bind(ABCFactory.class).toMockInstance(mockABCFactory);
 try
  {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ABCFactory.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockABCFactory);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ABCFactory.class);
    PowerMockito.when(ABCFactory.getFactory()).thenReturn(mockABCFactory);

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Mockito.when(mockABCFactory.getContext(domain)).thenReturn(null);
```

***Error:***
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:490)

---

What am I missing here. I have tried several other ways but ABCFactory.getFactory() always returns a new object but not my mocked object. How do I mock the behavior of ABCFactory class **without** changing its implementation?! Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use following annotations.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( ABCFactory.class )
```

I tried and following code works.

DocumentTest.class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( ABCFactory.class )
public class DocumentTest
{
  /** Unit under test. */
  private Document user;

  @Before public void setUp() {
     user = new Document();
     ABCFactory abc = ABCFactory.getFactory();
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(ABCFactory.class);
     PowerMockito.when(ABCFactory.getFactory()).thenReturn(abc);    
  }  

  @Test public void testABC() {
     assertEquals("", user.useFactory() );
  }
}
```

Document class

```
public class Document
{
 public String useFactory(){
   String profile = ABCFactory.getFactory().getContext("");
   return profile;
 }
}
```